# Upgrade path within MS Office 2007

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

Is there an upgrade path from MS Office 2007 Home and Student to the 2007 Standard or Profesional version? (i.e., getting Outlook and possibly MS Access.) We need to keep 2007 going for training purposes, so Office 2010 isn't an option at the moment.

**Edit**: It might be simpler to simply buy Office Pro 2007 online, it's not that expensive. If we do this, will installing Office Pro over the existing Office 2007 Home and Student suite cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no upgrade pricing/options for MS Office 2007.